# How to delete existing elements from an array and keep appending new elements afterwards

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

Below is an example, where I am using two arrays which could be initiated with many elements, for now having "None" as the only element, is there any way to delete existing element/elements and then keep appending new elements when given condition matches otherwise leave the array unaltered.

Looking for a way with minimal coding.

```
array_a=(None)
array_b=(None)
declare -A DICT=([1]="source" [11]="destination" [2]="nowhere")
for index in ${!DICT[@]} ; do
  [[ ${index} =~ 1 ]] && array_a+=("${DICT[${index}]}") 
  [[ ${index} =~ 50 ]] && array_b+=("${DICT[${index}]}")
done 
echo ${array_a[@]}
echo ${array_b[@]}
```

Output:

```
None destination source        
None
```

Expected Output:

```
destination source
None
```

I am having a dumb solution for this

```
array_a=(None)
array_b=(None)
declare -A DICT=([1]="source" [11]="destination" [2]="nowhere")
a=0
b=0
for index in ${!DICT[@]} ; do
if [[ ${index} =~ 1 ]] ; then if [[ ${a} -eq 0 ]] ; then ((a++)) ; unset array_a ; fi ; array_a+=("${DICT[${index}]}") ; fi
if [[ ${index} =~ 50 ]]; then if [[ ${b} -eq 0 ]] ; then ((b++)) ;  unset array_b ; fi ; array_b+=("${DICT[${index}]}") ; fi
done 
echo ${array_a[@]}
echo ${array_b[@]}
```

Output:

```
destination source
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ini_array_a=(None xyz)
ini_array_b=()
array_a=()
array_b=()
[...]
array_a=(${array_a[@]:-${ini_array_a[@]}})
array_b=(${array_b[@]:-${ini_array_b[@]}})
echo ${array_a[@]:-None}
echo ${array_b[@]:-None}
```

---

Where `$ini_array_a` and `$ini_array_b` are the already initialized arrays. We define two new arrays with no value inside. Then do your processing. For echoing the arrays, use [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The arrays `$array_a` and `array_b` are those to print in the end (this is to address your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465938/how-to-delete-existing-elements-from-an-array-and-keep-appending-new-elements-af/465948?noredirect=1#comment848511_465948)).

```
${parameter:-word}

    If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
    Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

Comment: Alternately, after the loop, `"${array_a[0]:=None}"` to assign a default value.

Comment: It would require to have a new loop through all the arrays, can it be adjusted in the same loop,  however question is assuming there are some existing elements in arrays.

Comment: @Bharat "some existing elements"? More than one? Please clarify the question with what you actually have and what parts of the code you can modify.

Comment: @muru Yes, I mean right now I am only considering None as the only element in array, but there could be many in it, eg. ( None xyz ...) so what I want if condition matches unset the array and append the elements, if it doesn't match just leave all the elements which were there initially i.e None xyz ...

Comment: @chaos Assumption is to have initialized arrays in the question.

Comment: @chaos  using new array for expansion, I guess It could create one more problem, lets say ini_array_b is not having any elements, this parameter expansion echo ${array_b[@]:-${ini_array_b[@]}} would make array_b of length 1 with null string in it. It would require additional code to fix.

Comment: @Bharat True indeed, forgot about that, now it should be as desired

Comment: @chaos now what would be the final elements of array_b based on your code

Comment: @Bharat It's empty, but array_a and array_b are just intermediate arrays. The needed arrays in the end would then be out_array_a and out_array_b. Maybe it's clearer this way (see my edit).